# Which system can provide an enjoyable RPG experience in 2 hours or less?

Tags: game-recommendation

I have recently started trying to convince a few friends at college to get into tabletop RPGs. Their major complain about it is that they do not often have 3+ hours to play a session, so I set looking for an RPG system that enables a fulfilling experience in 2 hours or less.

Here are a few things I am looking for in this game:

- Should have a focus on exploring character aspects and in character development, much like Fate.
- Should be geared towards or at least capable of providing a great experience on a short session(2 hours or less).
- Should not be open ended, like games such as Microscope. Players should have an objective goals and ways to achieve them.
- Should be easy to teach. Since we only have 2 hours to play we shouldn't be wasting half of that explaining the systems.
- Should enable playing with minimal preparation.
- Should enable both single session plays and long campaigns in case I can get the players hooked.
- Should either have a simple setting or be setting agnostic.
- Should have good mechanisms for player interaction and, if possible, competition between players amidst their cooperation, like in Paranoia.

Not all points are required, but I would be looking for a system that checks all of those. Specially the first two.

Comment: There are probably dozens, maybe even hundreds of games that qualify. Do you have some more critera for what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I changed it a bit. Is it specific enough now?

Comment: What does "play experience like Fate" mean? Can you break that down into elements which answerers can say "Yes, this game has it" or "No, this game lacks that"?

Comment: I thought that instead of comparing it to Fate, it might be more productive just specifying what composes the experience I want. Is it better?

Comment: This popped up in the review queue for reopening, so I wanted to comment here.  Game-rec questions are no longer on-topic here, so this shouldn't be reopened: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited